Can I add new environment values to an Azure Function App through an Azure Dev Ops Pipeline?
I have a Azure Dev Ops Pipeline, the first time it runs the deploy task (AzureFunctionApp@2) the environment values are added and set, and if i have values previously set in the pipeline they are changed, however when I add new values, they are simply ignored.
Is this expected, and whats the expected way to deal with it?
To be clear I was using the env field, but now i used the appSettings field its worked.
is env a legit field becuase i don't see it in the docs

All tasks have control options in addition to their task inputs. The env property is a list of string pairs that represent environment variables mapped into the task process. See the detailed info from Task environment variables.
According to doc Use application settings, The function app settings values can also be read in your code as environment variables. To set and update the environment variables in your function app, use appSettings in the AzureFunctionApp@2 task.

thanks for that, i got the appSettings to do what i wanted, but imo the env property is pointless because it only seems to be run the first time to pipeline is run, as nothing changes after that, while the appSettings property works all the time, and the docs you linked to doesn't mention anything about it.
